# overwriting css animation with !important

Tags: css, css-animations

So given this [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=223450) it's not reliable to overwrite an css animation using `!important`.

However, I'm in the following situation:

1. Open/ closing a list should be done by animating (using a css animation with keyframes) height on each of the elements in the list.
2. an order-by dropdown allows the elements in the list to be reordered. This is implemented by doing a `(jquery) detach` on all elements followed by an `(jquery) append` in the correct order. I want the reorder to happen instantly, without animations.

However, because of the detach/reattach the css animation kicks in again. resulting in a (albeit nicely animated) list growing from 0 height again to full-height no with elements in the correct order.

How to make bullet 2. work? I can't use css-classes to overwrite the height property using !important, because of the bug mentioned above. It seems there's no way to overwrite the properties set by the animation.

As an alternative I tried to set a css-class just before reorder (and remove just after reorder) that would do `animation: none`. Although that makes sure no animation happens during reorder, when I remove said class (and thus removing animation: none) AFTER the reorder happened, the initial css-class which has `animation: <the fade in anim>` for some reason kicks in the animation again, although it was already run once*

Any way out of this catch-22?

*) yeah I'm setting the animation as follows `animation: 0.2s ease 0s normal forwards 1 fadeinTdSpan;`, so it really should only run once. 
However, probably due to adding the node to another parent, the cycle of animation restarts.

Comment: Would flex/order help ?

Comment: I wish. The items in the list are TRs.. Setting flex on a table doesn't work. I'm thinking of actually doing a translateY on every row but that will get messy fast.

Comment: Do you have a demo online, that we can tinker with ?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I'll try to get that up tomorrow with a link. Thanks for the interest.

Comment: solved. Approached it backwards. Now I don't have an animation unless a specific class is set, I simply remove the class with animation once the animation is complete, and readd it when needed (i.e.: after a collapse has occured)